# How do I find the principal branch?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I'm trying to find the domain on which a function is analytic, specifically, $\text{Log}\left(\frac{1}{z}+i\right)$.

Would I need to find $\text{Log}\left(\frac{1}{z}+i\right)=\ln(r)+i\theta$ to find the branch cut?

How would I do that if $z=\frac{1}{z}+i$?

Comment: Hint: set $w = \frac{1}{z} + i$ and look at $\log(w)$

Comment: But how would I find the modulus of $\omega$?

Comment: Are you asking how to write a complex number $z$ in polar form, $z = r e^{i \theta}$? Typically you first draw a triangle, note where $x$ and $y$ are, and then compute an $\arctan$.

Comment: You just need to find the branch points. Remember $\log(z)$ has a branch point at $z =0$. What can you say about $\log(w)$ then?

Comment: so, log(w) has a branch point at $\frac{1}{z}+i$?

Comment: @Flloyd56: Finding $|w|$ is just simple algebra.  If using polar coordinates, $z = r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$, then $|w| = \frac{\sqrt{r^2 - 2r\sin\theta + 1}}{r}$, if I worked that out correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The branch points of the logarithm function, $\log(w)$, are at $w=0$ and the point at infinity.

If $w=\frac1z+i$, then $w=0$ when $z=i$.  And the point at infinity in the $w$-plane maps to $z=0$ in the $z$-plane.

The principal branch in the $w$-plane lies along the negative real axis.  This branch cut maps to the contour defined parametrically $z=\frac1{t-i}$, $t\in (-\infty,0]$, in the $z$-plane.

This contour is the semi-circular arc $x^2+(y-1/2)^2=1/4$, $x\in [-1/2,0]$.  And this is the branch cut for the principal branch of the function $\log\left(\frac1z+i\right)$.